# What user does WCF use to write?

Tags: c#, wcf, io

I currently have a WCF service that allows the client to upload an image to the server. The service then saves that image to the server's C drive as a test. This works, but I am curious as to *why* it works.

I was under the impression that the service was always executed as the IIS user, meaning that it would be stuck with whatever permissions the IIS user had at the time of execution. However, the folder that I am uploading to on the C drive does not list a permission for the IIS user at all. The only folder that has a permission for that user is that folder that actually contains the service and even then its only to read & execute.

So my question is, how is the service able to write to the C drive of the server when it is being run as a user with no security access for that directory?

Comment: Unable to know without your settings. What user does the service / application pool run under?

Comment: Service does not have to run under IIS user. Simpliest solution for you, to check owner of saved file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the WCF service is hosted in IIS then the actual code **doesn't** run under the IUSR user, rather it runs under the account you set for this particular application pool.

You can check the identity easily, just set up a simplest ASPX web page and paste this into the page's file

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

Current user: <%= System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name %>
```

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2010/09/identity-of-application-pool-in-iis.html